# Calculating Covariance matrix of higher dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance

I have the following matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\ 
 3& 4
\end{bmatrix}$$

I therefore compute the Covariance matrix using the following:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{(x_{i} - u_{i})({y_{i} - u_{i}})}{N}$$

This produces the correct output for a 2x2 matrix, or, any matrix x2 e.g.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\ 
4&4 \\
3 & 4 \\
3 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

On any other dimensions, e.g.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
4&4 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 4 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Will produce the wrong results, when comparing to those in MATLAB. In MATLAB I get:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2.25 & 0.33 & -0.58 \\
0.33 & 1.33 & -1.00 \\
-0.58 & -1.00 & 0.9167 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

And I get the result:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
6.75 & 1 & -1.75 \\
1 & 4 & -3 \\
-1.75 & -3 & 2.75 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I can't see where I'm going wrong. By the way when I use MATLAB, I just type: `cov(A)` Where `A = [1 2 3; 4 4 1; 3 2 2; 1 4 1]` and I'm calculating using pen and paper for now where I'm getting the wrong result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't worry!

You have the right answer! And `matlab` has the right answer too!

When using `matlab` you have to remember that it will allwas try to improve the results. If you see to your answer, you will observe that you can factorize the value $3$ of your matrix $A$.

`Matlab` has already done this and it is giving you the result after the factorization step has taken place, the result, the matrix $3A$ only that you don't see the $3$-value, I believe this is because `matlab` operates with orthonormal vectors.

You can find more info at the `matlab's` page.

Comment: Thanks :)! You don't know how many sheets of paper I've thrown away because of this! Is it worth factorising the results, however? I mean, will it effect the Eigen values and vectors?

Comment: No it will not! but you have to remember that you will be operating with eigenvectors which have 3 times more length that the ones `matlab` has. This is because this factorization I mentioned before :) Keep the good work, you are doing just fine! If my answer was helpful you can accepted as a valid-answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your kind words :) Do you have any resources on factorising the matrix? Like research papers or any online materials? Sorry I am trying to learn this - Thanks!

Comment: @user1326876 I am sorry but I have no material on the topic :( but I can let you know if I find something interesting! which topics are relevant for you?, in addition to covariance matrices.

Comment: Hey! That's okay thanks though. I'm interested in Linear algebra, and methods such as PCA and ICA (which I'm trying to calculate)! I've calculated the eigenvalues/vectors for a `2x2` and now going to move onto `3x3` etc.. I'm going to factorise the matrix so it's like matlabs results so I know I'm going right as I go along rather than getting different results ha

Comment: ok @user1326876 and do you need a matlab-code for the PCA? I have one which is based on the SVD, I can send it to you If you want, may be it will help you? I have been working with PCA myself, but these statistical methods are not my major :p I may have some theory which shows how the SVD is related to the PCA also, tell me if this sounds ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14925/discussion-between-user1326876-and-sergio-sarmiento).